# Permutation of puzzle pieces

Tags: java, recursion, permutation, puzzle

So I have managed to represent the puzzle pieces in form of an array of objects. Each puzzle piece can take 6 positions. So fitting the puzzle piece can be translated into a permutation problem, i.e, 6!. I want to implement it in java and [I found this algorithm](http://learnprogramming.machinesentience.com/java_permutations_recursion/).

My question is two fold. Is this an accurate translation of the algorithm?

```
List<Piece> permutation(List<Piece> prefix, List<Piece> seed){
    int n = seed.size();
    if (n == 0) {
        return prefix;
    }   
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            prefix.add(seed.get(i));
            List<Piece> newSeed = seed.subList(0, i);
            newSeed.addAll(seed.subList(i+1, n));
            permutation(prefix, newSeed); 
        }   
    }

    return null;
}
```

Secondly, if each piece can be rotated 4 times, and flipped and rotated 4 times again, i.e., each individual piece can be placed in 8 different ways in a single position, how do I extend the algorithm above to handle this? For simplicity, let's assume that you can access all 8 configurations of a piece in form a list using `List<Piece> list = Piece.getAllConfigurations()`. Any pointers?

Comment: What is the primary objective? I hope not to *print* all the permutations, since there is `188 743 680` of them (`6!*8^6`). If you want to find a way to piece together the puzzle, then you need a way to decide if puzzle A in position P is connectable to puzzle B in position Q from left, for example.

Comment: The objective is not to print. I have an algorithm that checks if the puzzles match given a certain configuration. The only thing remaining is to permute in order to get all combinations and find a solution.

Comment: And besides, it is not (6*8)! ?

Comment: it would be (6*8)! for 48 pieces, but you have 6! pice permutations and every of 6 pices can be rotated 8 different way which is independent of the position thus 8^6 totaling 8^6*6!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem can be solved in 2 phases, where
- phase 1 is a permutation problem P(6, 6)
- phase 2 is to orient each piece:   C(8, 1) ^ 6

Which leads to the number that kajacx mentioned above, for all possible cases:
6! * 8^6

I have some generic permutation and combination tool class here, which you might be able to just grab & use:
https://github.com/raistlic/raistlic-lib-commons-core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/raistlic/common/permutation